# is there a global function in windows to lists the files in a dir?

Tags: windows, winapi

which function windows is calling to list the files in a directory ?

thanks

Comment: You gotta be a little more specific.  Are you looking for some specific programming language syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this functions to do a directory listing with the WIN32 API.

[FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx), [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx) and [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413(VS.85).aspx)

A full example can be found here

[Listing the Files in a Directory WIN32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(VS.85).aspx)

For a portable approach check this post:

["Get list of files in a directory using c/c++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c/612176#612176)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't exactly get your question but won't using "dir" as system command do the job?
Correct me if I am wrong, coz the question itself wasn't very clear to me.

Edit - Hi John, this is the source code for listing directories.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(VS.85).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will be able to answer better if the question becomes clearer to me so if someone understands the question better, can they please edit it?

Comment: Hey,

in other words, im looking for the function that dir is using to list the files in a dir

thanks